# What happens to all the existing applications when a country decides to stop using daylight savings time?

Tags: .net

Is that just a matter of creating a new Windows patch and all is fine, or is there more scary stuff that is going to happen?

Comment: Do you mean daylight savings time? Because I'm not aware of any country that can actually opt out of participating in seasons.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Daylight savings time was somebody's idea to "save energy" by moving peoples' waking times depending on the season, but in the end all it causes is a hassle when the clocks have to be moved. And it's very likely countries will, at some point, stop using it. It's not something that's inherently "necessary" due to the fact seasons exist, and not all countries are using DST right now either.

Comment: Sorry, using the wrong terms, updated the title

Comment: "Summer time" is also a valid name for DST. It depends on where in the world you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe many applications will be fixed by operating system (there's many others besides Windows!), library and [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) updates and will require no modifications to the applications themselves. Because daylight saving time isn't even used in all regions of the world, applications that implement time correctly are inherently compatible with either having DST or not. It's just a matter of telling them to stop using it.

However that naturally only works for applications that only use standard libraries and timezone databases to reason about time. Applications that have hard-coded DST logic (or use a "statically linked" or equivalent library) will need to be updated. This would be especially fun for embedded devices that aren't designed to be easily updated.